# What is the purpose of "\0hidden" in an AF_UNIX socket path?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, ipc

I followed a tutorial on how to make two processes on Linux communicate using the Linux Sockets API, and that's the code it showed to make it happen:

**Connecting code:**

```c
char* socket_path = "\0hidden";
int fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_un addr;
memset(&addr, 0x0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
*addr.sun_path = '\0';
strncpy(addr.sun_path+1, socket_path+1, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-2);
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

**Listening code:**

```c
char* socket_path = "\0hidden";
struct sockaddr_un addr;
int fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&addr, 0x0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
*addr.sun_path = '\0';
strncpy(addr.sun_path+1, socket_path+1, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-2);
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
listen(fd, 5);
```

Basically, I have written a web server for a website in C, and a database management system in C++, and making them communicate (after a user's browser sends an HTTP request to my web server, which it's listening for using an AF_INET family socket, but that's not important here, just some context) using this mechanism.The database system is listening with its socket, and the web server connects to it using its own socket. It's been working perfectly fine.

However, I never understood what the purpose of a null byte at the beginning of the socket path is. Like, what the heck does `"\0hidden"` mean, or what does it do? I read the manpage on sockets, it says something about virtual sockets, but it's too technical for me to get what's going on. I also don't have a clear understanding of the concept of representing sockets as files with file descriptors. I don't understand the role of the `strncpy()` either. I don't even understand how the web server finds the database system with this code block, is it because their processes were both started from executables in the same directory, or is it because the database system is the only process on the entire system listening on an AF_UNIX socket, or what?

If someone could explain this piece of the Linux Sockets API that has been mystifying me for so long, I'd be really grateful. I've googled and looked at multiple places, and everyone simply seems to be using `"\0hidden"` without ever explaining it, as if it's some basic thing that everyone should know. Like, am I missing some piece of theory here or what? Massive thanks to anybody explaining in advance!

Comment: From the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html): "an abstract socket address is distinguished (from a pathname socket) by the fact that sun_path[0] is a null byte". This means the pathname is not a pathname in the file system but an abstract name for the socket.

Comment: The abstract socket address namespace is also described as a "nonportable Linux extension".

Comment: "I don't even understand how the web server finds the database system with this code block" The pathname is the same in both snippets. And that is how the webserver finds the database server. They must agree on the same socket name. You might also change it to `"\0databaseserver"`

Comment: So the OS keeps an internal set of socket names (only sockets that are using this part of the API) and it *connects* a socket to another *listening* socket only if they have the exact same entry in the `addr.sun_path` member of the sockaddr_un struct used in the `bind()` and `listen()` calls respectively, and they both begin with "\0" only if you do want to use this socket locating method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specific to the Linux kernel implementation of the `AF_UNIX` local sockets. If the character array which gives a socket name is an empty string, then the name doesn't refer to anything in the filesystem namespace; the remaining bytes of the character array are treated as an internal name sitting in the kernel's memory. Note that this name is not null-terminated; all bytes in the character array are significant, regardless of their value. (Therefore it is a good thing that your example program is doing a `memset` of the structure to zero bytes before copying in the name.)

This allows applications to have named socket rendezvous points that are not occupying nodes in the filesystem, and are therefore are more similar to TCP or UDP port numbers (which also don't sit in the file system).  These rendezvous points disappear automatically when all sockets referencing them are closed.

Nodes in the file system have some disadvantages. Creating and accessing them requires a storage device. To prevent that, they can be created in a temporary filesystem that exists in RAM like `tmpfs` in Linux; but `tmpfs` entries are almost certainly slower to access and take more RAM than a specialized entry in the `AF_UNIX` implementation.  Sockets that are needed temporarily (e.g. while an application is running) may stay around if the application crashes, needing external intervention to clean them up.

`hidden` is probably not a good name for a socket; programs should take advantage of the space and use something quasi-guaranteed not to clash with anyone else. The name allows over 100 characters, so it's probably a good idea to use some sort of UUID string.

The Linux Programmer's Manual `man` page calls this kind of address "abstract". It is distinct and different from "unnamed".

Any standard `AF_UNIX` implementation provides "unnamed" sockets which can be created in two ways: any `AF_UNIX` socket that has been created with `socket` but not given an address with `bind` is unamed; and the pair of sockets created by `socketpair` are unnamed.

For more information, see

```
man 7 unix
```

in some GNU/Linux distro that has the Linux Man Pages installed.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the explanation, you're a magician! I understand it better now for sure. Side question, is `The Linux Programming Interface` book from 2010 worth reading? Thank you immensely again for your details answer :)

Comment: I don't know; I haven't read any books of this type since long before 2010 and now. If you've never read any systems programming book of this type, it may be a good idea. Well over two decades ago I read APUE (Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment). After that era, I stopped consuming that type of stuff, "it all becomes the same", and you get better at reading the actual documentation and finding what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`\0` just puts a `NUL` character into the string. As a `NUL` characters is used to terminate a string, to all C string functions `socket_path` looks like an empty string, while in fact it is not but they would stop processing it after the first character.

So im memory `socket_path` actually looks like this:

```
char socket_path[] = { `\0`, `h`, `i`, `d`, `d`, `e`, `n`, `\0` };
```

As all strings automatically get a terminating `NUL` attached.

The line

```
strncpy(addr.sun_path+1, socket_path+1, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-2);
```

copies the bytes of `socket_path` to the socket address structure `addr`, yet skipping the first (`NUL`) byte as well as the last one (also `NUL`). Thus the address of the socket effectively is just the word `"hidden"`.

But as the first byte is left out from the `addr.sun_path` as well and this byte has been initialized to `NUL` by `memset` before, the actual path is still `\0hidden`.

So why would anyone do that? Probably to hide the socket, as normally systems show UNIX sockets in the file system as actual path entries but no file system I'm aware of can handle the `\0` character. So if the name has a `\0` character, it won't appear in the file system, yet such a characters is only allowed as the very first characters, otherwise the system would still try to create that path entry and fail and thus the socket creating would fail. Only as the first characters, the system will not even try to create it, which means you cannot see that socket by just calling `ls` in terminal and whoever wants to connect to it needs to know the name.

Note that this is not POSIX conform, as POSIX expects UNIX sockets to always appear in the file system and thus only characters that are legal for the file system in use are allowed as socket name. This will only work on Linux.

Comment: I know the semantics of C strings, what my question's about is what does "\0hidden" mean/do **in the context of the Linux Sockets API**. The comments seem to be doing a good job at explaining though :) thank you!

Comment: @KevinStefanov it is just the name of the socket. And the `\0` is required to distinguish these abstract pathname from a real pathname. It is like a string hidden behind an empty string.

Comment: I see, thank you very much @Gerhardh your comments really clarified it for me :)